# Phonegap - reliable page width detection?

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Can anybody recommend a good way to detect screen width on a HTML5 Android App built in Phonegap?

Our page is reasonably fluid - but I need to switch logo's/footer graphics for smaller screens - so I inject a stylesheet for smaller versions - seems to work fine in general, some phones (HTC Wildfire)seem to think they are 320px width when they are only 240 so I'm struggling!

This is my current detection code - any suggestions would be really helpful!

Cheers
Paul

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
 var pageWidth = $(window).width();
 var sizeSelected = "chilliAppBeta";
 alert(pageWidth);adjustCSS();

 function adjustCSS(){
 if (pageWidth >= 0) { if(pageWidth < 300) {alert("smallscreen"); applyChilliCSS();}  }
 if (pageWidth >= 300) { sizeSelected = "chilliAppBeta" }
 }

 function applyChilliCSS() {
 var chilliStyleSheet =$('<link href="CSS/chilliAppBetaSmall.css" rel="stylesheet"        class="chilliLink" type="text/css"/>');

 $('head').append(chilliStyleSheet);

 }
 });
```

Comment: I used jQuery's `$(window).width()` and `.height()` in Phonegap apps and it seemed to work just fine for me (also on my HTC Wildfire...). What version of Phonegap are you using and what's your target SDK?

Comment: Also, have you thought of using CSS3 Media Queries instead?

Comment: Target SDK is Andoid 2.2 and Phonegap version is http://www.webhosting.uk.com/.  Cheers for your help

Comment: Android 2+ and Phonegap 1.4 does return the right values for me unfortunately (good to know I cannot trust this). I'd opt for the media queries then, see this: http://jsfiddle.net/NLdLZ/ (resize the result) and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/ if you don't know what that is all about.

Comment: Cheers m90, media queries work a treat.  If you put your response as a answer I'll mark it as correct..  Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript to add additional rules based on your screen dimensions, you can use CSS3 Media Queries instead like:

```
.smallScreenContent{
display: none;
}
@media (max-width:400px){ //the following rules will only be used for screens up to 400px width
.smallScreenContent{
display: block;
}
}​
```

See this link for [specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) and this fiddle (resize the result) for a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NLdLZ/).

Answer (score 1):

The only way I found to correctly detect the window size is to put a timeout of a couple of seconds before to let the canvas fit the screen. At launch it shows up on the top left corner and only spreads to fit the screen after a short while.

Comment: The same thing goes with 'orientationchange' event. By the way I have this weird issue only on Android 2.X. On Android 3.X and higher everything is OK without timeout.

Comment: Ok, no need in timeout for page loading. Just use properly `document.addEventListener("deviceready", function(){/**/}, true)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$(window).width() // For width 
$(window).height() // For Height
```

Alternatively you could check the width of a `data-role="page"` element to find the `device-width` (since it's set to `100%` of the `device-width`):

```
var deviceWidth = 0;
$(window).bind('resize', function () {
    deviceWidth = $('[data-role="page"]').first().width());
}).trigger('resize');​​​
```

Comment: He's doing just this and asking for another way to do it as it doesn't seem to work....

Comment: Hi @m90 I added an alternate way :)

Comment: Neither worked for me - bothe produce the incorrect 320px width response!  Cheers for your help though..