# Media queries JavaScript also on browser working

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

I was trying something with JavaScript and media queries. I want to change some elements with JavaScript, like switching elements etc.

When the browser/device width is 320px I want to do something.

I came up with the following, but this doesn't work:

```
if (screen.width < 320){ 
    $('input[type="text"]').insertAfter('label');
    $('input[type="text"]').eq(1).remove();
    $('input[type="text"]').eq(2).remove();             
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I would like to do this for some changes of my CSS it looks like this:

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 400px) { }
```

And the example above I want to convert to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do so by using [**$(window).width()**](http://api.jquery.com/width/).

```
if ($(window).width() < 320) {    
  $('input[type="text"]').insertAfter('label');
  $('input[type="text"]').eq(1).remove();
  $('input[type="text"]').eq(2).remove();
}
```

Also, if you want to check if a resize has happened without refreshing, use **[$(window).resize()](http://api.jquery.com/resize/)**.

Here's an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UqYCr/611/) of resize in use.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work for me :( I tried your example above, but I don't get an alert that I have set inside your 2 examples... What does I wrong?

Comment: @Caspert How are you actually checking it? Have you console.logged what the width is? Why can't you just use media only screen and (max-width : 320px) { }

Comment: Yes I have try it, but I think I do it wrong: `console.log(window.width);` The reason that it can't work with css is because I want to replace some text inside an a element and also switch some objects...

Comment: @Caspert 'console.log($(window).width());' and 'console.log(window.screen.availWidth);'

Comment: Thanks for your answer and reminder. Now I get console all width's after refresh and make the browser smaller... Only this works for me: `if ($(window).width() < 320) {`. Is it also possible to change without refresh like mediaqueries inside css?

Comment: Thank you. Can I set simply your code inside that or should I replace `if ($(window).width() < 320) {` ?

Comment: @Caspert I guess you can just put the width() if statement inside of resize() one

Comment: You're my hero! Absolute thanks. It works what you had expect!

Answer (score 2):

You can call media queries inside JavaScript:

```
function resize() {
    if (window.matchMedia('only screen and (max-width: 400px)').matches) {
        document.body.style.background = 'red';                   
    } else if (window.matchMedia('only screen and (min-width: 401px) and ' +
                                 '(max-width: 600px)').matches) {
        document.body.style.background = 'blue';
    } else {
        document.body.style.background = 'yellow';               
    }
}

window.addEventListener('resize', resize, false);
resize();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below URL:

[Phonegap - reliable page width detection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9666870/phonegap-reliable-page-width-detection)

You can use Navigator object to detect the devices in jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.  Whilst media queries are great for css sometimes we need to load js based on the device size.

[Media Match](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/) written by Paul Irish is a great tool to do this.  It is used in [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) a feature detection library.